# In Blender how I can get an ImageSequence source filename in video editor (VSE)?

Tags: python, blender, vse

In Blender, when you use Video Editor (VSE), you can parse items using Python like this :

```
import bpy
import os

for seq in bpy.context.sequences:
  sFull_filename = ""
  if seq.type == "MOVIE":
    sFull_filename = seq.filepath
  if seq.type == "SOUND":
    sFull_filename = seq.sound.filepath
  if seq.type == "IMAGE":
    sFull_filename = "??"  # How to get it for images ?
    sName = seq.name       # /!\ It is not the file name !
    sPath = seq.directory
  # Finally
  sAbsolute_name = bpy.path.abspath( sFull_filename )
```

As you can see, I get the filename for movies and sound, but how can I get it for images ?

On Blender api documentation website I don't found how to do it...

I try to get VSE images strip file names...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the names from `elements` list of `seq`:

```py
    ...
    elif seq.type == "IMAGE":
        # Get the first image filename
        sFull_filename = os.path.join(seq.directory, seq.elements[0].filename)  

    sAbsolute_name = bpy.path.abspath(sFull_filename)
    print(sAbsolute_name)
```

or if you want them all, iterate over `seq.elements`

Comment: It works, thank you very much Marcin ! I've been looking for hours! :-)